# Operación con valor numérico de un dígito no arroja resultado esperado

Tags: c

Tengo este pequeño codigo

```
void main()
{
    int len,i;
    int rta[64];
    char numero[64];
    scanf("%s",numero);
    len = strlen(numero);
    i=0;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
        rta[i]=(int)numero[i]*2;
    }
    printf(rta);
}
```

Cuya entrada es `113` y resultado debería ser `226`, pero en vez de eso me arroja el siguiente resultado `b`

La idea es convertir los números a ***int*** y luego operarlos ya que necesito que la lea como una cadena inicialmente.

Alguna idea?

Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes ciertos problemas con el concepto de [codificación de caracteres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codificaci%C3%B3n_de_caracteres).

Para ser breve: el doble de un dígito **no tienen porqué coincidir con el doble de ese dídigo codificado**.

Tu introduces `113`, pero, en realidad, en la memoria se almacena una cosa bastante distinta:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) {
  const char input[] = "113";

  for( size_t index = 0; index < strlen( input ); ++index ) {
    printf( "[%d]", (int)( input[index] ) );
  }

  printf( "\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

Salida:

> [49] [49] [51]

Si aplicamos *a mano* tu algoritmo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {
  const char input[] = { 98, 98, 102, 0 };

  printf( "%s\n", input );

  return 0;
}
```

Obtenemos lo siguiente:

> bbf

#### ¿ Y porqué sale solo una 'b' ?

Esto es mas divertido, y entran en juego cosas como el [*endian*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) de la máquina. Para resumirlo, digamos que, en 32bits y *little-endian*, el número 49 se almacena como

> 00110001 00000000 00000000 00000000

Tu intentas leerlo como *cadena de caracteres*, con lo cual se interpreta por *paquetes* de 8bits ... y se deja de mostrar al llegar al primer `0`.

Y aún nos quedan cosas por comentar, como la influencia de haber declarado `rta` como una formación de `int` ... pero ya nos hemos extendido demasiado :-)

Bueno, pues terminamos ya. Tu código corregido, teniendo en cuenta toda la *parrafada* anterior, quedaría:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( ) {
  char rta[64];
  char numero[64];

  scanf( "%s", numero );

  for( unsigned i = 0; i < strlen( numero ); ++i ) {
    rta[i] = numero[i] - '0';
    rta[i] *= 2;
    rta[i] = rta[i] + '0';
  }

  printf( "%s", rta );

  return 0;
}
```

Como ves, realizamos la operación en 3 pasos:

1. **Descodificamos** el dígito.
2. Realizamos la operación.
3. **Codificamos** el dígito, para poder mostrarlo adecuadamente.

Observa que no tenemos en cuenta el posible *desbordamiento* al multiplicar por 2 un dígito ... ¿ Que pasa si introduces `999` ? :-)