# Evitar desbordamiento de numeros

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa basico que hace cálculos con números muy grandes, lo que hago es leerlo como `String` y la idea es que a cada dígito del numero lo multiplico por un numero grande (por ejemplo `100000`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>



int main( ) {
  char cadena[1000];
  char cadena2[1000];

  scanf( "%s", cadena2 );

  for( unsigned i = 0; i < strlen( cadena2 ); ++i ) {
    cadena[i] = cadena2[i] - '0';
    cadena[i] *= 100000;
    cadena[i] = cadena[i] + '0';
  }

  printf( "%s", cadena);

  return 0;
}
```

pero lógicamente se desborda y a la hora de imprimir, es decir no sale lo esperado.

Mi duda es como puedo guardar un numero tan grande que únicamente se deba leer como `String` ?

Gracias!

> PD: Ya habia hecho un pregunta asociado a este tema [Operación con valor numérico de un dígito no arroja resultado esperado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325519/operaci%c3%b3n-con-valor-num%c3%a9rico-de-un-d%c3%adgito-no-arroja-resultado-esperado/325532#325532)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres multiplicar cada dígito por `100000`, de entrada, tu cadena destino ha de tener un tamaño acorde: `1000 * 100000`. El resultado de eso es ... algo mas de 95M.

Usaremos formaciones ... pero, en previsión de problemas de tamaño, las crearemos de forma dinámica (podemos tener problemas con el límite de tamaño para la pila del Sistema Operativo).

Tenemos que tener en cuenta el tamaño de los tipos ... una multiplicación por `100000` **no cabe** en un `char`, puesto que el propio `char` solo admite en el rango `0` - `255`. Así que mejor usamos `int` para estas cosas.

Y, por último, para facilitarnos la vida, usaremos la función [`sprintf( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). Esta función es similar a `printf( )`, pero, en lugar de en un archivo, escribe en un *buffer* de memoria (que tenemos que gestionar nosotros). Es justamente lo que estamos buscando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( ) {
  char *resultado = malloc( 1000 * 100000 );
  char *iterator = resultado;
  char entrada[1000];

  scanf( "%s", entrada );

  for( unsigned i = 0; i < strlen( entrada ); ++i ) {
    entrada[i] -= '0';
    iterator += sprintf( iterator, "%d", entrada[i] * 100000 );
  }

  printf( "%s", resultado );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si tu escaneas un número como cadena, **no obtienes el número como tal** sino su representación en forma de caracteres. Es decir:

```
        00   01   02   03  <- offset memoria
123 ->  '1'  '2'  '3' '\0' <- caracteres
       0x30 0x31 0x32 0x00 <- representación hexadecimal
```

Así pues, el número 123, almacenado como cadena, resulta en la siguiente secuencia numérica (en hexadecimal): `30313200`.

Es facil ver que, en este caso, coger cualquiera de esos caracteres y multiplicarlo por 100000 no va a darte el resultado esperado.

Si optas por almacenar un número como secuencia de caracteres, tendrás que implementar todas las operaciones matemáticas involucradas, ya que la librería estándar no tiene ninguna utilidad al respecto. También podrías usar una librería de terceros.

Es decir, para sumar números podrías hacer algo tal que:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* ReverseArray(char const* arr, size_t size)
{
  char* result = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
  for (size_t i = 0, j=size-1; i < size; ++i, --j)
  {
      result[j] = arr[i];
  }

  return result;
}

char* SumarNumerosGrandes(char const* numero1, char const* numero2)
{
  size_t length1 = strlen(numero1);
  size_t length2 = strlen(numero2);
  if( length2 > length1 )
    return SumarNumerosGrandes(numero2, numero1);

  // Invertimos los números para simplificar las operaciones
  char* sec1 = ReverseArray(numero1, length1);
  char* sec2 = ReverseArray(numero2, length2);
  char* resultado = (char*)malloc((length1 + 3) * sizeof(char));

  size_t i;
  int acarreo = 0;
  for( i=0; i<length1; i++ )
  {
    int suma = (sec1[i] - 0x30) + acarreo;
    if( i < length2 )
      suma += (sec2[i] - 0x30);

    acarreo = 0;
    if( suma >= 10 )
    {
      acarreo = 1;
      suma -= 10;
    }

    resultado[i] = suma + 0x30;
  }

  if( acarreo != 0 )
  {
    resultado[i++] = acarreo + 0x30;
  }

  resultado[i] = '\0'; // Finalizamos el array

  char* toReturn = ReverseArray(resultado, i);

  // Liberamos la memoria dinámica
  free(sec1);
  free(sec2);
  free(resultado);

  return toReturn;
}
```